# Can i execute Shell command using FTPclient api java?

Tags: java, shell, ftp-client

Can i execute Shell command using `FTPclient` api  java?
I know that there are other FTP client api which allows it , but want to know if it is possible via `FTPClient` API only  .

Below code is for `SSHXcute api`

```
CustomTask ct1 = new ExecCommand("chmod 755 /hs/OCRInputFiles.tar.gz /home/pcats/OCROutputFolder.tar.gz /home/pcats/unTar.sh");
CustomTask ct2 = new ExecShellScript("/home/pcats", "unTar.sh", "hello world");
```

I want to do the same via `FTPclient`

Comment: does the ftp server allow you to execute shell command?

Comment: Seems you are mixing up ssh and ftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FTPClient`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) API supports the [`FTP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) protocol which does not have any concept of running commands on the remote server. The ability to run commands on the remote system would be considered a security risk for a file transfer protocol.

You're probably thinking of the [`SFTP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) protocol, which can run shell commands by invoking an ssh connection to the remote system. Being able to invoke commands on the remote system may not be possible because of limitations in the remote system (e.g. a windows based SFTP server), or for security reasons.

Comment: I have used Jsch api to do both .Thanks